# Kafka confluent 4.1.1 restart issue -- previously created topics not getting displayed

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am using kafka confluent-4.1.1. I created few topics and it worked well. I don't see previously created topics if I restart confluent.

I tried the suggestions mentioned in the post:
[Kafka topic no longer exists after restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34021794/kafka-topic-no-longer-exists-after-restart)

But no luck. Did any body face the same issue? Do I need to change any configurations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which command do you use?

Comment: check with this command : kafka_directory/bin/kafka-topics -list --zookeeper 109.XXX.XX.XX:2181

Comment: hsharma-mbp15:bin hsharma$ pwd .   
/Users/hsharma/confluent-4.1/confluent-4.1.1/bin .   
hsharma-mbp15:bin hsharma$ ./kafka-topics --list --zookeeper localhost:2181

Comment: @Alihosseinshahabi, I use the same command. Some configurations changes need to be done.

Comment: If you're using `confluent start`, then that puts all data in /tmp and won't be persisted over reboots

Comment: @cricket_007, thanks for the reply. What configuration changes do I need to do in order to persist?

Answer (score 0):

> What configuration changes do I need to do in order to persist?

`confluent start` will use the `CONFLUENT_CURRENT` environmental variable for all its data storage. If you export this to a static location, data should, in theory, persist across reboots.

Otherwise, the standard ways to run each component individually is what you would do in a production environment (e.g. `zookeeeper-start`, `kafka-server-start`, `schema-registry-start`, etc.), which will persist data in whatever settings you've given in their respective configuration files.